# Got error when running Kohana DB migration

Tags: php, migration, kohana

I am using Kohana php framework, when I try to run minion, I got this exception error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /system/classes/Kohana/Kohana/Exception.php on line 53
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /system/views/kohana/error.php on line 64
```

This is the code in Exception.php:

```
public function __construct($message = "", array $variables = NULL, $code = 0, Exception $previous = NULL)
    {
        // Set the message
        $message = __($message, $variables);

        // Pass the message and integer code to the parent
        parent::__construct($message, (int) $code, $previous);

        // Save the unmodified code
        // @link http://bugs.php.net/39615
        $this->code = $code;
    }
```

This is the code in error.php

```
{<?php echo __('PHP internal call') ?>}
```

Comment: Please show us the code of `Exception.php` & `error.php`

Comment: That function is defined in [`/system/classes/Kohana/I18n.php`](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/I18n.php#L155).  Make sure that your `system` directory isn't missing anything - the best thing is probably to re-download it.

Comment: Also, make sure that your `bootstrap.php` contains a call like this: `I18n::lang('en-us');` (though your language may be different if you choose).

Comment: Thank you Moshe Katz, your note worked for me.